# How to print all available python standard library methods in the terminal

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to list out all the standard library functions/methods (still learning the difference, I'm a noob). So I get how to import a module and use dir() and help(). These have been a great help and when I try to rewrite a program I learned to write and I get lost I try to use the dir() and help() to spark my memory.

However, for example, I was re-looking through some code and I had .replace() and I was scouring through my imported modules to find it and then found out it's in the standard library and a sub-part of the str() function. Is there something I can type into dir() that will spit out str()?

How can I print out all top level built in function/methods like I would when I do dir(re)?

I've tried re-wording this question in search engines several ways and I can't find anything and the results get muddied with "python list _____".

Thanks so much!

Comment: You had `.replace()` just hanging out on its own? Or was it used properly, as an attribute of a string, e.g. `mytext.replace(' ', '')`? That should be enough to tell you that it's an attribute of a string. If all you have is the word on its own, you can Google something like "python method replace" or simply go over the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/).

Comment: It was confusing because I was using one module to get a packet, another one to convert the packet and then I was setting an element of that packet as a variable and I wasn't sure if it was a method that was part of any of the 3 modules I imported. I didn't know if it was considered a string or a packet or a load. I'm learning as I go. Some of these modules have functions that are buried deep and can get confusing so I try to route my way from the top so I always know how to get back.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something I can type into dir() that will spit out str()?

`dir()` on a value of that type.

```
dir('hello') # string methods
dir(5) # integer methods
dir([]) # list methods
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know I could do that either, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I never tried typing just "dir()" that listed I could put in dir(__builtins__) and that is what I was looking for. I'll leave it here in case someone else is a noob too and knows where they can start. Just start with dir() and go down the rabbit hole!